# Running Ruby script in Terminal should 'stay awake' and not terminate once it gets to the end of the file

Tags: ruby, macos, terminal, eventmachine

I have a Ruby script which I'm testing in Terminal. With this code, it doesn't immediately return, but stays awake and prints any responses:

```
client = TweetStream::Client.new(credentials)
client.on_direct_message do |direct_message|
    puts 'direct message: ' + direct_message.text
end

client.userstream
```

But now, in order to test a number of these clients at once, I need to put them in their own thread, like so:

```
Thread.new do
    client = TweetStream::Client.new(credentials)

    client.on_direct_message do |direct_message|
        puts 'direct message: ' + direct_message.text
    end
end
```

The problem then is that the Ruby script returns immediately. How can I make it not immediately return, and stay awake until I do cmd+c to close it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can ask Ruby to wait until thread is done by using [#join](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Thread.html#method-i-join)

```
t = Thread.new do
  client = TweetStream::Client.new(credentials)

  client.on_direct_message do |direct_message|
    puts 'direct message: ' + direct_message.text
  end
end

t.join
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `Thread.stop` helps you. This will stop the thread.
If you call the thread with `join` method, the ruby waits until finish the thread. In this case will wait until you kill process.

```
t = Thread.new do
  puts "Test"
  sleep 1
  puts "wait for kill"
  Thread.stop
end

t.join
```